# transform() or override() or centerCrop() not working with glide Android

Tags: android, transform, image-resizing, android-glide

This app currently is working perfectly fetches and displays images but when I try to add additional methods to glide in the ImageListAdapter class like `override()` or `centerCrop()` or `transform()` or `placeholder()`, it doesn't work. I mean it doesn't even let me add those, it shows in red and no similar suggestion but many tutorials suggest to use those methods to modify size, why does it not work. Am I doing something wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.imnobody.photosearch;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         String[] eatFoodyImages = {
                "http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/aIy5R2k.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/MoJs9pT.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/S963yEM.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/rLR2cyc.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/SEPdUIx.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/aC9OjaM.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/76Jfv9b.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/fUX7EIB.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/syELajx.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/COzBnru.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/Z3QjilA.jpg",
        };

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        ImageListAdapter imageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this,eatFoodyImages);

        gridView.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);

    }
}
```

**ImageListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.imnobody.photosearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by imnobody on 5/8/17.
 */

public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        private String[] imageUrls;

        public ImageListAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
            super(context, R.layout.image_main, imageUrls);

            this.context = context;
            this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_main, parent, false);
            }

            Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .load(imageUrls[position])
                    .into((ImageView) convertView);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**activitymain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.imnobody.photosearch.MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">
</GridView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**image_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagemain"/>
```

Comment: Are you using Glide v4? If so, see http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions.